# Fetch single image url from list of multiple image Url using Glide Library

Tags: android, android-glide

Adapter

```
RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(model.getUrlToImage())
            .apply(requestOptions)
            .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
            .into(holder.imageView);
```

This image shows UrlToImage with multiple Urls

[image: This image shows UrlToImage with multiple Urls]

I am using Glide library to fetch Image from API. My Code is working Properly when UrlToImage has only one Url but in case of multiple urls my code isn't working. No image is being fetched in case of multiple URLs. I need help to get this resolved.

Comment: How you are settling multiple URLs in glide ?

Comment: I see no UrlToImage. I see no multiple urls.

Answer (score 0):

From the Image of the API Response you posted, I think it's quite simple.

1. First, check if multiple url's exist in the urlToImage response String. (By checking if urlToImage.split(",") is greater than one or something.)
2. If multiple url's exist, choose first one or anything else by accessing the array of the split URLs
   (for eg String[] array = urlToImage.split(",");
   array[0] gives first image url etc etc ...)